# Horizontally align objects in front or side 2D views

Tags: transforms, transform-orientation

Is there a way to horizontally align the "red object" in the exact centre of the blue lines?

[image]

Comment: What are the blue lines? Can you center/snap the 3D cursor to their center?

Comment: Presuming that the gray rectangles are one object, enter edit mode, select the horizontal rectangles, press shift S to activate the snap function and select "cursor to selected". The 3d cursor will move to the center of the horizontal rectangles. Then select the vertical object, press Shift S snap and select "selection to cursor"

Comment: Blue lines are just for reference made in Photoshop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Snap <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> the cursor to vertices that will align it where you want the object to be (e.g., four corner vertices that are equally spaced apart vertically and/or horizontally).
2. Snap <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> the object to the cursor position.

[image]

Note: this assumes that the origin is at the center of the single plane. If not, you could set the origin to the center with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (origin to geometry) or go into edit mode, select the vertices you want to move and do <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (selection to cursor (offset)).

Comment: ayy bb how you get them pie menus

Comment: @Different55 Search for *pie menu* in User Preferences --> Add-ons.